# Installing a web application with Wix gives me a 1603 error

Tags: iis-7, wix

After doing some research, I learned that a 1603 error means that the site cannot be found.  In my case, I'm looking for the DefaultWebSite.  Now I've probably deleted and recreated a site called "Default" on my IIS7 installation since the last time I've messed with this installer.  How do I get the default website back or get something in there that Wix understands to be the default Website so that I can install virtual directories to it?

Here is a copy of the fragment in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="WEBDIRECTORY">
      <Component Id="SiteInstallationComponent" Guid="MYGUID">
        <CreateFolder />
        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="ProductVirtualDirectory" Alias="[PRODUCTVERSION]" Directory="WEBDIRECTORY" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <iis:WebSite Id='DefaultWebSite' Description='Default Web Site' Directory='WEBDIRECTORY'>
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
    </iis:WebSite>
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="Default" Name="DefaultAppPool" />

  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I'm very lost as to how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

1603 is just a general generic windows installer error that means the install failed.  You need to generate a verbose log and look through it for additional information.